# RxSwift FirebaseDatabase snapshot <null> when handling launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, rx-swift

Object exists on firebase.  Opening a detail view based on the object ID.
It works fine when app is backgrounded and the function is called from

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

When the app is killed and the notification handled the snapshot comes back null.

App Delegate:

```
AppName.shared.user.shareReplayLatestWhileConnected().filterNil().distinctUntilChanged({ lhs, rhs in
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }).subscribe() { event in
        switch event {
        case .next(let user):
            self.userIdString = user.key
           ...
            if let notificationInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any] {
                self.handleMessageFromRemoteNotification(notificationInfo)
                }
            }...
```

Handler:

```
Event.load(url.lastPathComponent).single().subscribe(onNext: { event in
            //prepare and present view here...
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Failing event loading function:

```
static func load(_ id: String) -> Observable<Event> {
    return Observable.create() { observer in
        FirebaseDatabase.sharedInstance.ref.child("events/\(id)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            snapshot in
            //This the null snapshot
            if snapshot.exists() {
                if let event = Event(snapshot: snapshot) {
                    observer.onNext(event)
                }
                observer.on(.completed)
            } else {
                observer.on(.completed)
            }
        })
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment

```
FirebaseDatabase.sharedInstance.ref.child("events/\(id)").observe(.value
```

As opposed to

```
FirebaseDatabase.sharedInstance.ref.child("events/\(id)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value
```

Seems to solve it, will comment with more.